# Fetchmail to given destination

Tags: email

I'm using fetchmail to download messages from a POP3 mail-relay account into Lotus Notes. The problem is that fetchmail tries to deliver to fetchmail@mydomain.com and not to john@mydomain.com. The incomming messages has a field with the real destination like this:

```
X-Original-To: john@mydomain.com
```

How can I configure fetchmail to deliver to this destination ?

Answer (score 0):

The man pages say

> **--smtpname**        (Keyword: smtpname)
>   Specify the domain and user to be put in RCPT TO lines shipped to SMTP. The default user
>   is the current local user.

Pretty much the same in the [.fetchmailrc](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/fetchmail-man.html#31)

> smtpname          Specify the user and domain to be put in RCPT TO lines